# Can we get this unlinked?

Tags: support, duplicates, question-closure

[Word that describes a stand in or a frontman?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571633/word-that-describes-a-stand-in-or-a-frontman/571636#571636) was referred to another question, [Word for Powerless Position?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265902/word-for-powerless-position), which apparently did not answer the question, as the questioner selected my response as the one they were seeking on their question, an answer not offered for the other question.

Comment: Linking (i.e. cross-referencing) the questions that are in **some** way related, even if they are not duplicates of each other, is generally regarded as desirable. In this case, a person looking at one of the two pages may find it helpful to also look at the other, so there is no reason to unlink them. What you seem to want to say is that neither page is a duplicate of the other, which is a different matter from linking/unlinking them.

Comment: @jsw29 I should hope it is clear that they are not duplicates, but neither are they asking the same question.

Comment: Indeed, but they are asking **related** questions, and that is a sufficient reason for linking them. Would you still object if neither question were closed as a duplicate, but someone posted a comment below one of them saying that it is related to the other and providing a link to it? That would make them linked, without implying that they are the same.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates “If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, edit it to highlight the differences, then try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote.”

Comment: @ColleenV I can't cast a reopen vote. That's the point.

Comment: @GArthurBrown There are a few more words in the sentence I excerpted than “cast a reopen vote”.

Comment: @ColleenV If you copied that text and think that is not the key part of the sentence, then I really wonder why you are involved in an English site at all.

Comment: Is your reading comprehension truly that poor? …edit it to highlight the differences, **then** try to get it reopened.,

Answer (score 4):

What has happened is that the 1st question was closed as a duplicate of the 2nd. The system of closing is what made the link (by the choice of the user who closed it, who, by the design of the system, was allowed to do this as a single person).

To undo this link, you'd have to get the closed question -reopened-, by the usual means.

As to the suitability of reopening, I think you need to make a reasonable case for it. Your justification is a bit hard to follow and what of it that I do follow is not very convincing. Just because a questioner approves an answer doesn't mean it is 'correct' and subsumes all possible answers.

Comment: None of that made a lick of sense. The questioner obviously felt the link did not answer question.

Comment: Did the part about the mechanism for 'unlinking' at least make sense? There's no editable URL link in the question or answer to unlink. But the way to remove that notice about the duplicate is to get the item reopened (thus removing the close reason).

Comment: It appears you've answer your own question.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I'm trying to help you out rhetorically. It looked like you didn't understand the process of how the link got there, and I was trying to explain. And it also looks like you didn't understand that that was what I was trying to do. This comment is an attempt to explain my first comment which was intended to explain my answer which was intended to answer your question. I have a feeling this comment  is not going to help you but I'm just stating it in case it helps explain things to anybody.

Answer (score 4):

Why would we want to split answers between the same question asked slightly different ways? If someone is looking for a “word for someone who holds a position but they have no real power” they should be able to see *all* of the answers we have to that question on the site.

Closing a question as a duplicate doesn’t affect your answer or its acceptance by the author, so I’m not sure what you would hope to accomplish by having it reopened. The link would in theory make your answer more visible.

Comment: Because these are two different questions.